# How to get&build latest version of NHibernate.Search?

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate.search

This is silly, but i can't understand how to do it.

Checked out from svn (https://nhcontrib.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/nhcontrib) source, but when i try to build it, there's bunch of errors about FullTextSessionImpl which does not implement ISession interface members.

Tried hornGet, but it shows "The build tool Horn.Core.NAntBuildTool
failed building the nhibernate.search package" error)

Tried to rebuild \branches\NHibernate.Search-NH3.x
\NHibernate.Search.csproj - project can't find some references.

Tried to add them from \trunk\lib, \branches\lib\net\3.5, got few
"FullTextSessionImpl does not implement something" and some other
errors, so - i guess i didn't find appropriate dll's.

What am i doing wrong?

Basically - I just want to get NHibernate.Search version that has
**NHSR-25** patch included. Any tips how to do that?

Posted the same on [NHusers](http://groups.google.com/group/nhusers/browse_thread/thread/7083cdfff8c6a5b4)

---

This is getting unbelievably frustrating. Now I'm completely confused.

[image]

[image]

Tried both - NHS trunk version & NHS 3.x version with freshly built NH trunk assemblies - still nothing.

Ran `NAnt -D:with.core.only=true` command when building NH.

I just don't understand what I'm missing.

---

Turns out i `svn co` nhibernate from nhcontrib svn. -_-

Nah... that didn't help either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trunk version of NHibernate.Search builds against NH2.1, for a trunk build of NH you want the branch version NHibernate.Search-NH3.x

I just built this from current svn by doing the following:

- svn co the NH trunk
- build it with NAnt (resulting assemblies are under build)
- svn co NHibernate.Search-NH3.x
- delete references to Iesi and NHibernate, and replace with the freshly built ones
- fetch log4net and Lucene assemblies from NHibernate.Search/lib in trunk
- build NHibernate.Search with Visual Studio

Update: NHSR-25 has only been applied to trunk. You will need to add the patch yourself, use the smaller of the two from the JIRA.

Comment: I guess that's what happens when one uses SVN once a few months only... -_- Ty.

Comment: Sounds promising... Will check.

Comment: Now that's a user friendly process if I ever saw one.

Comment: Did what you wrote. Still nothing. :D

Answer (score 1):

You can reliably pull a build from hornget:

http://hornget.net/packages/orm/nhcontrib/nhibernate.search/

this will include search and all its dependancies :)

Comment: I noticed hornget, but it didn't include patch i was looking for. :/

Comment: 'trunk version' throws this => 'The build tool Horn.Core.NAntBuildTool failed building the nhibernate.search package'

Answer (score 0):

Turns out - it's simple! Of course! So intuitive! :D

Anyway - here it is...

nhibernate.search.csproj=>

```
<DefineConstants>TRACE;NHIBERNATE20</DefineConstants>
```

must be changed to

```
<DefineConstants>TRACE;NHIBERNATE30</DefineConstants>
```

because of statements like

```
#if !NHIBERNATE20
        public EntityMode ActiveEntityMode
        {
            get { return session.ActiveEntityMode; }
        }
#endif
```